# Import Error for Flask-Bcrypt with Google App Engine: ImportError: No module named bcrypt._bcrypt

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I am trying to deploy my flask application to Google App Engine. After much toil I've finally been able to upload my libraries but when I use the command `dev_appserver.py` I always get this error concering Flask-bcrypt:

```
 File "/Users/drubio/Desktop/blackduck_directory/venv/gaenv/flask_bcrypt.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise e
ImportError: No module named bcrypt._bcrypt
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before? I've found these resources regarding flask-bcrypt here [Flask-bcrypt for GAE not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027196/how-can-i-use-bcrypt-scrypt-on-appengine-for-python) and here [How to use py-bcrypt with GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482258/how-to-use-bcrypt-on-google-app-engine-gae).

From these resources I've learned that FLask-Bcrypt might not be written as a pure python package which it needs to be for GAE to upload and second there is another alternative called py-bcrypt. However while looking at its github  page, it seems to be abandonware so I don't want to waste time with that? Are there any suggestions anyone has out there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use bcrypt/scrypt on appengine for Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027196/how-can-i-use-bcrypt-scrypt-on-appengine-for-python)

Comment: Hi, I know it's quite a long time, but could you remember how did you fix this problem?

Comment: If you're still looking for solutions for this, look at the duplicate question linked to above.